# Produce long, strong, flexible shavings

Tags: wood, strength, traditional-techniques

Ainu people (indigenous to Japan) use long wood shavings as a material to weave or braid into headpieces.  The movie *Ainu Mosir* includes a scene that demonstrates the process of shaving down a green stave with a sharp knife.  The stave was about .5 meter long and the shavings stayed full length.  When they were later braided/woven, they made a strong material.

What properties would make a wood suitable for this task? Does anyone know what wood the Ainu use? I know they use elm to make clothes, so this could be elm as well. I am also looking for any potential temperate alternatives.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  A photo or sketch of a headpiece may help posters offer better answers.

Comment: *"What properties would make a wood suitable for this task?"* The main property here is they start with green wood, which is **extremely** easy to plane into long, unbroken shavings compared to dried/seasoned wood. So, do you have or could you secure a source of green wood? Even if they do use elm as you posit, expect your local species (whether you're in NA or Europe) to differ somewhat to **significanty**, in the same way that European sycamore is no match for American maple.

Comment: *"I know they use elm to make clothes"* I could go look this up but isn't that from the layer under the bark? Obviously this does suggest there's a good chance they're using multiple parts of the same tree as an efficient way of using a natural resource, but it's just as possible they use another species for the shavings and use the wood from the elms for something else..... even as firewood!

Comment: Yes, fibers are taken from the inner bark and spun just like wool or flax for the clothes.  But these shavings of interest are definitely proper xylem. I could certainly wrangle up some low or high-density green hardwoods or some green softwood. I guess I'll just experiment around until I find something that doesn't dry too brittle... Probably start with willow or alder.

Comment: @DuncanOcel I've inadvertently had some pretty long shavings from green ash (European).  That might be worth a shot, though I'm not sure how brittle it will be dry

Comment: Some NA indigenous peoples also made clothing out of woven or spun wood fibre.